# Linq string.Join group values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following query and I would like to get a comma seperated list of Locs in the property LValues.

```
from sci in sit

  join i in it on sci.ItemId equals i.Id into it
    from i in it.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join sc in sc on sci.ISId equals sc.Id
  join l in Loc on sc.Id equals l.ESId

  group new { l, sci, i } by new { i.Code, i.Name  } into g
  select new 
  {
      Code = g.Key.Code,
      Name = g.Key.Name ?? "UNKNOWN",
      LValues = string.Join(',', g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).Distinct()), // This is not working
      Qty = g.Sum(x => x.sci.Qty)
  }
```

I'm using EF Core 3.1.3 and Linq says

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { 
>       Code = (i.Code), 
>       Name = (i.Name),   },  ElementSelector:new { 
>       l = (EntityShaperExpression: 
>           EntityType: Loc
>           ValueBufferExpression: 
>               (ProjectionBindingExpression: l)
>           IsNullable: False
>       ), 
>       sci = (EntityShaperExpression: 
>           EntityType: Sit
>           ValueBufferExpression: 
>               (ProjectionBindingExpression: sci)
>           IsNullable: False
>       ), 
>       i = (EntityShaperExpression: 
>           EntityType: It
>           ValueBufferExpression: 
>               (ProjectionBindingExpression: i)
>           IsNullable: True
>       )  } )
>       .Select(x => x.l.LValue)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
>   evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
>   AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

If I use an aggregate function like g.Max(x=>x.l.LValue) it gives one value as expected. Is there any other way than using client side evaluation? However I have tried `string.Join(',', g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).ToList().Distinct())` but that didn't work either, throws the same error.

**Update**

It throws the same error even with `LValues = g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue)` or `LValues = g`. There must be something in my data or the group by that makes it fail.

Generated SQL (Sql Server) looks like this using `LValues = g.Max(x=>x.l.LValue)` in linq:

```
SELECT [i0].[Code], COALESCE([i0].[Name], N'UNKNOWN') AS [Name],
    MAX([l].[LValue]) AS [LValues], SUM([i].[Qty]) AS [Qty]
FROM [Sit] AS [i]
LEFT JOIN [It] AS [i0] ON [i].[ItemId] = [i0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Sc] AS [i1] ON [i].[ISId] = [i1].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Loc] AS [l] ON [i1].[Id] = [l].[ESId]
GROUP BY [i0].[Code], [i0].[Name]
```

I hope this helps understand what is causing the error.

Comment: EF cannot translate `string.Join` into SQL, so you need to pull the values from the DB and then in memory do the `Join`.

Comment: @juharr It can't translate g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).Distinct() without string.Join either.

Comment: What if you add a `ToList` to the end of it?

Comment: @juharr Same error.

Comment: What if you get rid of the `Distinct`?  You can always do that part in memory too.  This sort of non-sense is why my company hasn't updated to Core as we're waiting for EF to actually work again.

Comment: @juharr It throws the same with only `g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue)`.

Comment: What if you just do `select g`, then do all of the stuff in your select in memory?  Also it doesn't look like you need `i` in the group.

Comment: `select g` throws the error, too. I've added the generated SQL.

Comment: It's looking like Core cannot handle group by.  So you might have to do the grouping in memory as well.  Basically I think it can only handle selecting the Key or doing aggregate functions when you do a group by.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to materialize your data and concatenate string on client side, cause EF can not translate `string.Join` into proper SQL:

```
var query = from sci in sit

  join i in it on sci.ItemId equals i.Id into it
    from i in it.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join sc in sc on sci.ISId equals sc.Id
  join l in Loc on sc.Id equals l.ESId

  group new { l, sci, i } by new { i.Code, i.Name  } into g
  select new 
  {
      Code = g.Key.Code,
      Name = g.Key.Name ?? "UNKNOWN",
      LValues = g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).Distinct(), 
      Qty = g.Sum(x => x.sci.Qty)
  };

var result = query.ToList()
  .Select(o => new
  {
      LValues = string.Join(",", o.LValues)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. With `LValues = g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).Distinct(),` it couldn't be translated either.

Comment: Try move `Distinct` to result selection also. Like `LValues = g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue).ToLIst()` in query.

Comment: It throws the same with only `g.Select(x=>x.l.LValue)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do the grouping in memory as EF Core can only do basic aggregate functions in a select when using a group by

```
(from sci in sit
join i in it on sci.ItemId equals i.Id into it
from i in it.DefaultIfEmpty()
join sc in sc on sci.ISId equals sc.Id
join l in Loc on sc.Id equals l.ESId
select new 
{
    i.Code,
    i.Name,
    l.LValue,
    sci.Qty
})
.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Name })
.Select(grp => new
{
    Code = grp.Key.Code,
    Name = grp.Key.Name ?? "UNKNOWN",
    LValues = string.Join(',', grp.Select(x=>x.LValue).Distinct()), 
    Qty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty)
});
```

I switched from query syntax to method to better show what is done in the DB and what is done in memory but you can use either syntax through out.